# Нужно ли использовать разные таблицы хранения комментариев в подобном проекте?

Tags: mysql, хранение-данных, блок-схема

Нужно ли использовать разные таблицы хранения комментариев в подобном проекте?

Или же можно использовать одну таблицу общую?

Хотелось бы услышать мнения на этот счет...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ответ зависит от того, являются ли оба типа комментария одной сущностью в рамках анализа предметной области, или это две различные сущности. Судя по схеме, это две независимые сущности, просто имеющие много сходных черт и, в рамках русского языка, похожее название. К тому же, опять же из схемы, мне кажется сомнительным наличие процесса совместной обработки обоих типов комментария. В общем, две разные таблицы мне кажутся более предпочтительным вариантом.

Comment: @Akina А чего в них различного-то, то, что одни относятся к разным типам материала? Тогда уж, раз они еще и к разным материалам будут относиться и от разных пользователей, то можно на каждую связку материал-пользователь отдельную таблицу заводить... Судя по схеме структуры БД, в transport_comment и в article_comment входят независимые обїекты, но сами объекты структурно одинаковые. Так что, навскидку одной таблицы с доп.  колонкой `comment_type` вполне... А вот постобработка уже может диктовать свои новые требования. Но из схемы БД наванговать, что с комментами будут делать, нельзя.

Answer (score 0):

Зная только структуру, дать какой-то конкретный ответ нельзя. Нужно знать, что с этими комментариями будет совершаться.

Например, если они будут тупо сохраняться/выводиться/удаляться и стандартные выборки по материалу, автору и т.п., то одной таблички вполне хватит хоть на пару миллионов записей (только индексы правильно проставить нужно).

Если же будет какой-то сложный поиск по содержимому этих коментов или какая-то дичь типа морфологического анализа прилагаемых файлов, то придется городить доп. структуры данных (не обязательно/только таблицы, может файловую БД или еще что-то). Но нужно знать "что, где, куда"...

Comment: Из вашего ответа ясно то что либо вы не умеете читать структуру, либо просто ее не смотрели, а значит и ответ ваш не имеет смысла.